# Use Material Design and Caliburn.Micro simalteniously

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, material-design, caliburn.micro

I use WPF, and C#. I want to use both `:MaterialDesign` and [Caliburn.Micro v4.0173](https://caliburnmicro.com/) in one solution in Visual Studio. I have tried to add both of them to App.xaml, but materialDesign does not work. So the view of controls is the same as if I don't installed materialDesign.

```xml
<Application x:Class="WPFUI.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFUI">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper"/>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MD1" Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MD2" Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MD3" Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.BlueGrey.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MD4" Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MD5" Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.DataGrid.ComboBox.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Can you add some more details as to what is going wrong. *"it does't work"* does not give much to go on.

Comment: Which version of caliburn micro are you using?